# If one was to separate [0,4] into four equal sets, what would the correct notation be?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, continuity, notation

If one was to separate [0,4] into four equal sets of positive real numbers, would the result be:

> [0,1), [1,2), [2,3), [3,4)

or

> (0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)

or something else?

Comment: Neither of those will cover the original set. If we take the union, then in both examples $4$ will be missing. Also, can you clarify what you mean by "equal"?

Comment: Thank you! By equal I meant something along the lines of  isomorphic/same cardinality/feature a complete bijection, though I understand that these a difficult properties for infinite sets. So, which of my suggestions would be preferable? Or is there a better way to separate the set?

Comment: if you mean just same cardinality (i.e. there is a bijection between them), then this isn't too hard, because every real interval has the same cardinality. But this is probably not what you are after because something like $[0, 0.001], (0.001,  0.5), [0.5, 0.7), [0.7, 4]$ would work, and there are far uglier examples.

Comment: No that's definitely not what I'm after. I suppose what I mean is that the ranges within each set should be equal, such that the the maximal magnitudes of each set less the minimal magnitudes is equal.

Comment: I guess you mean measure,  then. How long the intervals are,  per say.

Comment: Random guess: if you need an isomorphism, you can't do it, because isomorphism preservers closed/openness, and you can't have four half-open/half-closed intervals cover [0,4] because the first set would have to be `[0,1)`, the last one `(3,4]`, which means the second one would have to be `[1,2)`, meaning the remaining one would have to be closed on both ends, `[2,3]`. You might be able to do it with more unusual sets.

Comment: @barrycarter this was my intuition also. I was just wondering if there is indeed some unusual set that could do it! =)

Comment: @barrycarter, isomorphism of which kind of structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Four Congruent Parts

Based on the comments, it seems that one possible intended/desired meaning of "equal" is (geometrically) "congruent" (in the sense that each part can be reflected and/or translated to become exactly the same another part).

For that meaning, the answer is that it **can't be done**. But I don't think that's at all obvious. I cite [Partitioning an Interval Into Finitely Many Congruent Parts](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969525) by William Gustin. Basically, he proves that for a problem that's at all like this: if it can be done, then it can be done with intervals. And as the OP basically notes, it's clear it's impossible to break $[0,4]$ into four congruent intervals.

## Four Parts of the Same Cardinality

As [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375650/if-one-was-to-separate-0-1-into-four-equal-sets-what-would-the-correct-notati#comment6945952_3375650) by [another Mark](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/661457/mark-kamsma) in the comments, a partition such as $\left\{[0,0.001], (0.001,\frac12), [\frac12,0.7), [0.7,4]\right\}$ would have four parts of the same cardinality.

## Four Parts of the Same "Length"

In measure theory, the concept of "Length" is generalized to "lebesgue measure", which generally agrees with total length any time you would have intuition about length. The measure/length is the same for a closed interval and a half-open one, so a partition such as $\left\{[0,1), [1,2), [2,3), [3,4]\right\}$ would have four parts of the same length/measure.